# Add a string before product name

Tags: python, django, string

In the following code, I would like to add a string called "ABC" before appending the product name

```
table_po= set()
    for tr in orders:

        table_po.add(str(tr.product))
    table_data.append(table_po)
```

After execution, it could be like ABC = Cat where Cat is the {tr.product} value

Comment: it's python. li.append(f"ABC: {tr.xxx}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [fstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

`table_po.add(f'ABC = {str(tr.product)}')`